# Calculating the following Integral

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

Here is the question which I need help to calculate:

> Knowing that $\displaystyle \int_2^3 (2f(x) - 3g(x)) dx = 2 $   and $\displaystyle \int_2^3 g(t)dt = -1$, 
>   find the value of $$\int_2^3 (3f(s) + 2g(s)) ds$$

I do not even know where to start for such a question, any tips of where to start off would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: First use the first two pieces of information and the linearity of the definite integral to find $\int_2^3 f(x)\,dx$.

Comment: Question not clear. PLease make it clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting $A=\int_{2}^{3}f(x)dx, B=\int_{2}^{3}g(x)dx$ may make it easier to solve the question. Then you'll have $$2A-3B=2, B=-1\Rightarrow A=-1/2,B=-1.$$
Hence, the answer will be $$3A+2B=-3/2-2=-7/2.$$

Comment: The only part i dont understand now is that the question gives you information about f(x),g(x) and g(t) and then asks you to calculate f(s)-g(s).. there are 5 different functions in this, how can we use values from the on function on the other?

Comment: @JoshBoiskin: Note that $\int f(x)dx=\int f(s)ds=\int f(t)dt$. The same integral with different letters.

Answer (score 4):

If
$$\int_{2}^3g(t)dt=-1$$
and
$$\int_{2}^3(2f(x)-3g(x))dx=2$$
then
$$\int_{2}^3(2f(x)-3g(x))dx=2\int_{2}^3f(x)dx-3\int_{2}^3g(x))dx=$$
$$=2\int_{2}^3f(x)dx-3\cdot(-1)=2\Rightarrow\int_{2}^3f(x)dx=-\frac{1}{2}$$
$$\int_{2}^3(3f(s)+2g(s))ds=3\cdot(-\frac{1}{2})+2\cdot(-1)=-\frac{7}{2}$$

Comment: Hello Adi. I dis-activated my FB account for days. Nice to meet you :+)

Answer (score 0):

This is really essentially an algebra problem, once you use the given conditions and the linearity of the integral. This is one way to proceed: As $\int \limits_{x=2} ^{x=3} 2f - 3g = 2$, and $\int \limits_{x=2} ^{x=3} g = -1$, then
$$
\int \limits_{x=2} ^{x=3} f = 
\frac{1}{2} \int \limits_{x=2} ^{x=3} 2f =
\frac{1}{2} \int \limits_{x=2} ^{x=3} (2f - 3g + 3g) =
\frac{1}{2} \int \limits_{x=2} ^{x=3} (2f - 3g) + \frac{3}{2} \int \limits_{x=2} ^{x=3} g =
\frac{1}{2} \cdot 2 + \frac{3}{2} \cdot (-1) = - \frac{1}{2}
.
$$
Hence, 
$$
\int \limits_{x=2} ^{x=3} 3f + 2g 
= 3 \int \limits_{x=2} ^{x=3} f + 2 \int \limits_{x=2} g 
= - \frac{3}{2} + (-2) = - \frac{7}{2}.
$$
I see others beat me here - however, as I have it written up, perhaps a multitutde of solutions will be helpful, so I will post it anyways.